# How do I execute this line once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I got this line here and I'm really really struggling hard with executing the *is offline* part once.

It shows once, when the user is online. That's okay. But when the user turns offline it says `--- is offline` every 10 seconds in the console. I only want it to say `is offline` when the user turns offline and then stop until it's online again. Please help me out here.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('statusIndexer') == null)
    return;
  for (var i = 0; i < WLAPStore.Presence.models.length; i++) {
    var m = WLAPStore.Presence.models[i];
    var id = 'p' + m.id.slice(0, -5);
    var clientBox = document.getElementById(id);
    if (clientBox !== null) {
      var img = clientBox.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      img.classList.remove('isOnline');
      if (m.isOnline) {
        console.log(id + ' is online');
        clientBox.parentNode.prepend(clientBox);
        img.classList.remove('isOffline');
        img.classList.add('isOnline');
      } else {
        console.log(id + ' is offline');
        clientBox.parentNode.prepend(clientBox);
        img.classList.remove('isOnline');
        img.classList.add('isOffline');
        (document.getElementById('statusIndexer') == null)
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: we can't help you if you don't share all the necessary code to reproduce your problem. You seem to be running this in a loop and checking every 10 seconds, maybe don't do that if you don't want something printed every 10 seconds

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't the complete code and you are using an interval somewhere. If that is the case you need to store the return value from setInterval and when you want to stop it you need to call clearInterval and pass in the value you stored earlier. If this isn't the case then update your question and I will take a look and see if i can help.

Comment: is this code inside an timeoutfunction or setinterval? or how do check if the user is online?

Comment: How are you calling this code, that it is repeating every 10s?
There are plenty of options. My preferred would be either 1) Keep a last state variable and check that the state has change before running this code. 2) stop the timer or whatever is calling this and restart when clicking to be online.

Comment: Can you post calling code? It sounds like you have unexpected an `setInterval` somewhere..

Comment: @Luca i've posted the whole section now. Hope it helps + I'm really confused, don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: @MIG if you want to prevent the view from being updated on each interval check, you have to store that state somewhere outside your interval function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global variable to hold the previous state, and check if it changed before logging the message.

```js
var onlineState = {};

window.setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('statusIndexer') == null)
    return;
  for (var i = 0; i < WLAPStore.Presence.models.length; i++) {
    var m = WLAPStore.Presence.models[i];
    var id = 'p' + m.id.slice(0, -5);
    var clientBox = document.getElementById(id);
    if (clientBox !== null) {
      var img = clientBox.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      img.classList.remove('isOnline');
      if (m.isOnline) {
        if (m.isOnline !== onlineState[id]) {
          console.log(id + ' is online');
        }
        clientBox.parentNode.prepend(clientBox);
        img.classList.remove('isOffline');
        img.classList.add('isOnline');
      } else {
        if (m.isOnline !== onlineState[id]) {
          console.log(id + ' is offline');
        }
        clientBox.parentNode.prepend(clientBox);
        img.classList.remove('isOnline');
        img.classList.add('isOffline');
        (document.getElementById('statusIndexer') == null)
        return;
      }
      onlineState[id] = m.isOnline;
    }

  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It still spammed "is Offline" every second but I think I found a way. You're awesome!

Comment: If your solution is different from mine, you should post yours as an answer, and accept that instead.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the online state is different for different models.

Comment: I've changed the global variable to an object that uses the IDs as keys, so it keeps track of each model's state separately.

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid. This must be really easy to you. Thank you very much!